# codeigniter returning false from models

Tags: php, codeigniter

Just wondering if it is necessary to use `else {return false;}` in my codeigniter model functions or `if () {}` is enough and it returns false by default in case of failure?

**controller:**

```
if ($this->model_a->did()) {    
                $data["results"] = $this->model_a->did();
                echo json_encode($data);
            }
```

**model:**

```
public function did()
    {    
      //some code here    
        if ($query && $query->num_rows() > 0) {
            return $query->result_array();
        } else {
            return false;
        }    
    }
```

Comment: It all depends on what exactly, you're trying to do. I never did a else in model, coz i always know there would be a result data to be sent from model. Can you be specific on what exactly you're looking at ??

Comment: its good practice for a return type function to return default value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your controller -- test the negative condition first - if nothing came back from the method in your model

```
if ( ! $data["results"] = $this->model_a->did() ) {    

    $this->showNoResults() ; }

else { echo json_encode($data); }
```

so thats saying - if nothing came back - then go to the showNoResults() method.
If results did come back then its assigned to $data

**However** - in this situation in the model i would also put ELSE return false - some people would say its extra code but for me it makes it clearer what is happening. Versus methods that always return some value.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is more of a PHP question than a CodeIgniter question. You could easily test this by calling your model methods and var_dump-ing the result. If you return nothing from a method in PHP, the return value is NULL.

Answer (score 1):

As much i have experience in CI returning false is not a plus point, because if you return false here then you need to have a condition back in controller which is useless you should be doing like this will save you at least some code of lines

```
if ($query && $query->num_rows() > 0) {
return $query->result_array();
} else {
return array();
}
```

so returning an array will save you from many other errors, like type error.